# How can I wait for the finish of execution of a command in Unix?

Tags: python, bash, shell, unix, csh

I have 25 processor in a compute node.

I have a main python script A that a) runs in a loop 3) Performs `20 tasks` in every loop that is also distributed among the 25 processors.

Main Python Script A

```
Lots of calculations

os.system("csh subtask.csh; wait")

Lots of calculations
Return to beginning of loop
```

Where, `subtask.csh` is of this type:

```
./model -h 1 controlfile
./model -h 2 controlfile
./model -h 3 controlfile
./model -h 4 controlfile
./model -h 5 controlfile
... 
./model -h 20 controlfile
```

But, this way, my program doesn't wait for `subtask.csh` to finish.

How can I make it wait?

Comment: It probably *does* wait for `subtask.csh` to finish (and the `wait` command won't do anything since there's nothing to wait for). If `subtask.csh` or `./model` spawns background processes, they won't be visible to the caller.

Comment: Thanks, I found out just now that the jobs are not being distributed across processors and it is going serially....

Comment: So, is there a different way to wait, where I know what these subprocesses are doing?

Comment: I'm wondering if he runs his subtask.csh in `&` (background mode) or do the same at `./model -h N control file level` (actually at this level, it should be a loop as well inside subtask.csh) and put (append mode) the PID of the last background process `foo & ; echo $! >> some_pids_file.txt` and instead of using `wait` at all, outside that subtask.csh (sub-shell) he can just have a loop which re-creates the some_pids_file.txt every time for all PIDs that you had or any `./model .. ...` process and when this file is EMPTY then the loop breaks. I think that's maximusdooku's best bet.

Comment: I would use `&` inside subtask.csh file for each `./model ... .. &` run

Comment: What does `./model` do? If it invokes background processes and doesn't tell you about them, there's not much you can do (unless you do something like reverse engineering the process name(s)).

Answer (score 0):

can you try using this ??

```
./model -h 1 controlfile &
./model -h 2 controlfile &
./model -h 3 controlfile &
./model -h 4 controlfile &
./model -h 5 controlfile &
wait
```